# Find/replace: regex with some logic, quotes – from input file to output file, single pass

Tags: regex, linux, bash, replace, sed

I have a file:

**input.txt**:

```
a|400|green|blahblah|big
b|2500|red|text|small
a|1400|blue|something|medium
```

and I want to convert it to

**output.txt** (note different quotes):

```
color: "green"; size: "big"; price: 400
color: 'red'; size: 'small'; price: 2500
color: "blue"; size: "medium"; price: 1400
```

That is, regex to find:

```
^[ab]\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|.*?\|(.*?)$
```

and replace with the following:

- if a line starts with `a|`:

  `color: "\2"; size: "\3"; price: \1`
- if a line starts with `b|`:

  `color: '\2'; size: '\3'; price: \1`

How to do this in Unix command-line, or sed, or Cygwin, or Bash, in a single pass? The higher the performance, the better (those files are really huge)

Comment: `sed` accepts multiple expressions. `awk` also accepts multiple matching rules. what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```perl
#!awk -f
BEGIN     {FS = "|" }
$1 == "a" {z  = "\""}
$1 == "b" {z  = "'" }
$0 = "color: " z$3z "; size: " z$5z "; price: " $2
```

Run like this

```
foo.awk input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I accepted this and I'll test it. I'll add a comment if I have additional questions

Comment: @StevenPenny: `$1=="a" ? "\"" : "'"` looks visually appropriate if I have only two conditions. But what if I have 5-7 test conditions? Is there another syntax (something like `switch $1="a" --> ..., switch $1="b" --> ...`)?

Comment: @StevenPenny: Oh, stop. You simply store the columns in $, but I use this example only as a **demo**! Actually, I'll need to keep **regex references** as variables, not columns! For example, `^[ab]_(.*?)\|(.*?);.*?\|(.*?)$`- how do I keep `var1`, `var2`, `var3` excluding the 3rd column?..

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `awk` command:

```
awk -F '\\|' -v sq="'" '$1=="a"{q="\""} $1=="b"{q=sq} {
   printf "color: %s%s%s; size: %s%s%s; price: %s\n", 
   q, $3, q, q, $5, q, $2}' input.txt > output.txt
color: "green"; size: "big"; price: 400
color: 'red'; size: 'small'; price: 2500
color: "blue"; size: "medium"; price: 1400
```

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj: I overlooked that part. Corrected now.

Comment: Why did you include the output in here? I expected to see only filenames instead.

Comment: @lyricallywicked: That is just for demo purpose. You can of course add `> output.txt` in front of `awk` command to store this output in a file.

Comment: Thank you. Is this supposed to be typed in command-line? Please, edit this to show where exactly are the both filenames.

Comment: Sure I updated it to show full `awk` command. Typed multiline just to avoid horizontal scroll.

Comment: Thank you, really. Well, it seems very complex to look at, I don't understand the internals of how this works (I'm a novice in this field). And I'd like to see the performance comparison because it's really important

Comment: Actually it is one of the simpler awk command I've posted here. We're holding a single quote in variable `sq` and using custom field separator as `|`. Rest is just `printf` command for formatted output.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -e "s/^a|/\"/;s/^b|/'/;s/\(.\)\([^|]*\)|\([^|]*\).*|\([^|]*\)/color: \1\3\1; size: \1\4\1; price: \2/" YourFile
```

posix sed (so `--posix`on GNU sed)

Comment: Is this single pass? That is, when a line starts with some pattern, I perform some replace operations only at this line, and then continue to the next line?

Comment: yes, it change each line, one at a time (this default sed behaviour), by reforamting, send to output thant go to next line. It reformat only if pattern is matching (leaving other line the same).

Answer (score 1):

Similar to anubhavas but with a different approach, would have been a little difficult to write in a comment.
Obviously this assumes there can only be an `a` or a `b` as the first field

```
awk -F'|' '{q=$1=="a"?"\x22":"\x27"}
           {print "color:",q$3q"; size:",q$5q"; price:",$2 }' file
```

How it works

Sets Field separator to `|`
Sets variable q to either a `'` or `"` based on if the first field is an `a` using the hex values of them
Then prints the line with the quotes replaced by the value in q

Simple enough !